# How to access my webapp using public IP address instead of localhost?

Tags: java, servlets, localhost, webserver

Is it possible to access my web application using public IP address like,

`http:/AppServerIP:8180/myWar/myServlet`

If I hit through Web Server like below it works fine (`Servlet` gets invoked)

`http:/WebServerIP(public)/myWar/myServlet`

When am trying to invoke the `Servlet` from my Application Server, am getting the below exception.

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
```

`Servlet` gets invoked internally through code when another end User concurrently logs into same port. So, I want to call that `Servlet` and invalidate the current session. I don't want to go through Web server as it might send the request to other ports as well.

My project Stack : Jboss AS 5.1.0 GA, Apache web server 2.2.5 and **Port Number  is 8180**

Comment: do comment and if my solution is helpful then accept it otherwise let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to get your public IP address, which you can find using `ipconfig` command on Windows machine.

Then, you can try like this

```
http://<your_public_ip_address>:<your_webserver_port>/
```

It will show you server welcome page. And you need to open your specific project. Then, try this

```
 http://<your_public_ip_address>:<your_webserver_port>/myproject/
```

It will show, your `index` or `home` page of your project.

**Note :** You need to be sure for your **IP Address** and **Port Number**